# Navigation component popup to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the navigation component. Let's suppose you have these possible navigations

```
A -> C -> D -> E
B -> C -> D -> E
```

So you can start a sequence of screens from the two fragments A and B.
Let's suppose that from E you need to go back to the fragment that started the sequence so either A or B.
I can store the id of the fragment that started the sequence and then go to that using `setPopUpTo` when calling the action to navigate.

Is there another way to do it? Something to say `pop up to C inclusive`? And this should pop up C,D and E and go back to the original fragment without me specifying it.
In other words I just want to keep popping up the fragments until the fragment I specify (C in this case) is popped up too.

Comment: I think when you are navigating from A or B it will create stack accordingly. so you don't have to navigate. just use ` navController.popBackStack()`

Comment: The question is whether there is a way to popup more than one fragment to get rid of all the fragments in the sequence C->D->E without having to popup many times.@AmmarAbdullah

Comment: For that case use `navController.popBackStack(R.id.action_group_to_preview, false)`

Comment: how did I not find it?! Thank you

Comment: Glad to help you! I have added my comment as an answer as well for future comers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To popup your stack you can use

```
navController.popBackStack(R.id.action_group_to_preview, false)
```

Answer (score 2):

to avoid rememer destination in backstack you can do in this way(kotlin):

```
   val firstFragment = findNavController().backQueue.firstOrNull { it.destination.id == R.id.fragmentA }?.destination?.id
   firstFragment?.let {
      val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
      navOptions.setPopUpTo(firstFragment,false)
      findNavController().navigate(firstFragment,null,navOptions.build())
    }
```

Comment: Sorry maybe the question should have been more explicit the fragments A and B are not always the first fragments in the backstack

Comment: i updated my answer, please check

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah method is cleaner. I'm upvoting this one anyway. thanks

Comment: @1048576 If Ammar method is clear then why you can't upvote to Ammar?? Upvote to Ammar and also accept answer .